# Criteria when selecting keyboard for piano learning

Tags: piano, learning, keyboard

I would like to start learning to play the piano, and since I do not have the space nor the funds for a complete piano, I would like to buy a keyboard instead.

My questions:
How many keys do I need as a beginner? Do I really need 88 keys?

Are weighted keys and something like velocity-sensitive keys (keys that play louder when hit harder) useful or maybe even necessary?

How much money should I calculate with for a keyboard that suits my needs?

Thank you in advance for answering and sorry if this might be a duplicate of another question, but I could not find anything.

Answer (score 0):

I think it really depends on what you want to play down the road.  If you want to play the piano, you really need a keyboard with properly weighted keys (the ones that actually have the hammer mechanism inside seem to be the only ones realistic enough to do the job) so you are comfortable with piano action and can learn how play with the correct expression.  On the other hand, if your goal isn't ever really to play the piano, but rather you're aiming for the organ or just synths in general, then the lighter "synth action" would be preferable in my opinion as (typical) organ and synth keys do not have the resistance of a proper piano action and either don't respond to velocity at all, or respond in a very different way than a piano.  You'll find many different opinions on this, but it really boils down to what you want to play in the future.